# An entity relationship diagram shows the relationship between entities, but how do you show the relationship between attributes?

Tags: data-science, computer-science, entity-relationship, modeling, erd

Say I had three types of vehicle, which are all related by some similar attributes.

[image]

What is the best way to show these relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In traditional entity-relationship diagrams such a relation between attributes is not shown.  This notation is exclusively reserved for foreign keys to primary keys relationships. For example if you would have a `Manufacturer` entity with a  (unique) `Id` attribute,  you could then relate a new attribute `Car manufacturer id` to it to show to what entity it refers.

In an [enhanced ERD](http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/dbms/eermodel.htm), you could use the `IsA` relationship and move the common attributes to a separate entity called `Vehicle`.  The `IsA` relationship would then mean that the same attributes are inherited by the inheriting entities. But your example is not straight forward,  since a `Boat` has no `Number of wheels`.  So you'd need to further add a `Rolling vehicle` entity, making the diagram very complex.

Very pragmatically,  you could:

- Use the same attribute name for the same kind of information.
- Use a data dictionary describing each unique attribute in a generic way applicable to all teh entities that use it.
- Or graphically use some dotted connector between common attributes (instead of the plain lines which are confusing)
- Or, if the similar entities are close on the diagram, draw colored horizontal boxes surrounding groups of identical attributes.